# How can I make Wordpress redirect all requests to subdomain.domain1.com to www.domain2.com

Tags: regex, wordpress, .htaccess, iis, mod-rewrite

As the question says really, How can I make Wordpress redirect all requests to subdomain.domain1.com to www.domain2.com.

I have a wordpress site on windows azure - I've added the below to the htaccess file but nothing seems to be happening:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.*)subdomain.domain1.com/$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.domain2.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

Comment: when you use a dot/period/. in a regular expression like you have, it matches any character (Other than a line break I believe). You should escape them using backslash \

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your rule to:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^subdomain\.domain1\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://www.domain2.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L]
```

1. Make sure to place this rule on top of all other rules in your .htaccess.
2. Make sure to reflect same domain change in `WP permalink settings`

The following is the comments summarised into the answer:

For wordpress sites hosted on on azure (and therefore in IIS) you dont use the htaccess file for rewrites, you actually need to add a web.config as described here http://www.davebost.com/2013/07/11/moving-a-wordpress-blog-to-windows-azure-part-5-moving-from-a-subfolder-to-the-root

The following rewrite rule would achieve the required result:

```
...
<rule name="Redirects to www.domain2.com" patternSyntax="ECMAScript" stopProcessing="true">
    <match url=".*" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAny">
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^subdomain.domain1.net$" />
    </conditions>
    <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.domain2.com/{R:0}" />
</rule>
...
```

Comment: This still isn't working - could there be any other reason why? I can see that the regex matches correctly, but requests to my website aren't being redirected correctly.

Comment: Can you test in a different browser.

Comment: Also can you open the request in Firefox/Chrome browser with Firebug window turned and and see if you get 301 response twice or only once? (You can use curl/wget from Unix command line also)

Comment: I don't get any 301 responses, everything comes back as 200's

Comment: Do you ever see `www.domain2.com` in your browser? Can you post your complete `.htaccess` code?

Comment: The domain1 is codenutz.azurewebsites.net and second is www.codenutz.com - codenutz.com responds fine, its just the azure one wont redirect. The snippet I posted is my entire htaccess file (with he correct domains switched in)!

Comment: But I thought `codenutz.azurewebsites.net` has Wordpress running. If yes then it should have some WP rules also isn't it?

Comment: Both domains point to the same instance of wordpress. I'm dont really understand esht you mean by WP rules.

Comment: Wordpress has its own rewrite rule in a `.htaccess`. Where exactly is that located?

Comment: The .htaccess file was empty when I starting editing it. It only has the contents from my original question.

Comment: There is some confusion because WP always needs 2 rewrite rules to function. THat must be in a separate .htaccess or in the same .htaccess

Comment: Looking into this it might be related to the fact that my wordpress installation is on IIS

Comment: Oh IIS!! I didn't know about that. So .htaccess on IIS does not need rewrite rules?

Comment: It looks like in IIS you dont use the htaccess file for rewrites, you actually use a web.config file. http://www.davebost.com/2013/07/11/moving-a-wordpress-blog-to-windows-azure-part-5-moving-from-a-subfolder-to-the-root

Comment: Ok thanks, let me read more about mod_rewrite on IIS. I don't have IIS so won't be able to test but if I find something I will edit my answer.